# STM32f407 - Existence of bugs in the simultaneous use of usart and SD-card

Tags: c, stm32, sd-card, usart, stm32cubeide

I want to receive data via USART and save it on SD-card. To do this, I have activated "sdio 4 bit" and USART with global interrupt.
When my codes contains SD-card command, some of the received data is lost during storage in buffer  and even when it sending back data this isn't same as received data.
But when I delete SD-card command it store data on buffer and send back data completely and correct.

SD-card command:

```
                 if(f_mount(&myFatFS, SDPath,1)==FR_OK)
                 {
                     //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_SET);
                     
                     char myFileName[]="TEST1.TXT";
                     if (f_open(&myFile,myFileName,FA_WRITE | FA_OPEN_ALWAYS)==FR_OK)
                     {
                         //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG,GPIO_PIN_2,GPIO_PIN_SET);
                         
                         f_lseek(&myFile, f_size(&myFile));
                         if(f_write(&myFile,store_data_1,sizeof(store_data_1),&myBytes)==FR_OK)
                         {
                             //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG,GPIO_PIN_3,GPIO_PIN_SET)
                            
                         }
                         f_close(&myFile);
                     }
                 }
```

even when I use f_mount one time in codes and dont use the rest of the code it act same.
How can I use SD-card without data lost?
I use stm32f407 and cubeIDE1.7 .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show more of your code. From this snippet no UART I/O code (with which you diagnose the problems) is visible.

Comment: "*Existence of bugs ...*" -- Until you have presented a clear demonstration of the problem that can be replicated by others, you need to assume that the problem is in your code.